# Using component both as custom element and as angular component

Tags: angular, web-component, angular6, custom-element

I'm trying to use an Angular component as a custom element so I can add it to the DOM dinamically and it is automatically bootstraped, but I also need this component as part of another component's template.

I have registered a *Description* component as a custom element and it is correctly bootstrapped anytime I add the following to the dom:

```
<app-description text="Some description text..."></app-description>
```

But, if I want to use that component as part of a *Header* component's template (which has an attribute descriptionText properly set) I get no description shown. I'm using it like this:

```
<app-description text="{{descriptionText}}"></app-description>
```

I've also tried:

```
<app-description [text]="descriptionText"></app-description>
```

and

```
<app-description text="descriptionText"></app-description>
```

but I don't get the expected result in any case.

So, my question is: 
**is there a way to define an Angular component as a custom element and also be able to include it inside any Angular component's template?**

**Edit:**
I put a console.log() inside the ngOnInit method in Header and Description components and I'm getting this printed in the console:

[image]

It seems that the component is initialized two times and in the second one 'text' is set to undefined?

Description component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-description',
  templateUrl: './description.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./description.component.css']
})
export class DescriptionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() text: String;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('text:', this.text)
  }
}
```

Description template:

```
<div class="description">
    <h3>{{ text }}</h3>
</div>
```

Header component:

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.less']
  })
  export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() title: String;
    @Input() subtitle: String;
    @Input() descriptionText: String;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log('descriptionText:', this.descriptionText)
    }
  }
```

Header template:

```
<div class="header flex-container">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ subtitle }}</h2>
    {{descriptionText}} <!-- shown correctly! -->
    <app-description text="{{descriptionText}}"></app-description>
</div>
```

Module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    DescriptionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    DescriptionComponent
  ],
  schemas : [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
}) 

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.registerCustomElements();
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {}

  registerCustomElements() {
    const HeaderElement = createCustomElement(HeaderComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('app-header', HeaderElement);

    const DescriptionElement = createCustomElement(DescriptionComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('app-description', DescriptionElement);
  }
}
```

**I am using angular custom elements provided in Angular 6**

Thanks!

Comment: All of what you have should have worked (except the last; that's the literal "descriptionText" and not the variable. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bradley. I'm not getting any console errors, but what I see is that the property 'text' is not being passed to the component.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET please see my edit, I added more information. Thanks!

Comment: Getting initialized twice is very odd; could you post more code or even link to a working sample on GitHub?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I added some code in the edit!

Comment: where do you initialize descriptionText in HeaderComponent ?

Comment: Thanks @AnassAnas! In my index.html I have the following:

`<app-header title="Title" subtitle="Subtitle" description-text="Description"></app-header>`

Comment: @Bruno you won't get the component's input when bootstrapped, try to get the tag attribute.

Comment: @Abr001am thank you for your help! Could you explain me a bit more what you mean with getting the tag attribute?

Comment: [look here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6mmw3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your time! What you say is that the input values are not available at bootstraping, so I have to get them by getting the attributes of the tag from the DOM? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, as far as i know, and as soon it's not implemented in the newest versions of angular.

Comment: @Abr001am I'm getting null trying to get the text property from the DOM. And also couldn't add an <app-component> to the index.html and get it rendered.

Comment: You don't see app-component's frgments rendered because you need to load their constructors with `Renderer` element.

Comment: [see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6ttng?file=src%2Findex.html)

Comment: Great! Now description is renderer. But if I add `<app-header title="Title" subtitle="Subtitle" descriptionText="Description"></app-header>` to the index.html, the header is not rendered.

Comment: @Bruno holy capuccino, that's because you need to bootstrap both of them, [see now](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6ttng?file=src%2Findex.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved using the following code, the issue was with something related with the nested css code then you need to put in your child custom element (in this case `<app-description>`) the following line `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and I changed the var `descriptionTest` to `description`

**description.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-description',
  templateUrl: './description.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./description.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**description.component.html**

```
<div>
    {{text}}
</div>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
  @Input() title: String;
  @Input() subtitle: String;
  @Input() description: String;
```

**header.component.html**

```
    <div class="header flex-container">
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      <h2>{{ subtitle }}</h2>
      {{description}} <!-- shown correctly! -->
      <app-description text="{{description}}"></app-description>
    </div>

**App.module.ts**

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,      
    HeaderComponent,
    DescriptionComponent  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
  ],  
  providers: [],
  entryComponents:[
    HeaderComponent,
    DescriptionComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.registerCustomElements();
  }

  registerCustomElements() {
    const DescriptionElement = createCustomElement(DescriptionComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('app-description', DescriptionElement);

    const HeaderElement = createCustomElement(HeaderComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('app-header', HeaderElement);       
  }
```

**Index.html**

```
 <app-root>
  </app-root>
  <app-description text="'HOLA!'"></app-description>

  <app-header title="Title"
      subtitle="Subtitle"
      description="DESCRIPTION"
  ></app-header>
```

[src](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7400)

[image: output]

[github repository](https://github.com/AbelValdez/Angular-customelements-child) with this example

Comment: Thank you, Abel!! Are you registering the components as custom elements as I did in my code? Are you under Angular 6? Today I tried doing that, as another user suggested, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, even I'm using your same code Module, components etc. just the call in app.component is changed by  `descriptionText` instead  `description-text`

Comment: Take a look to this [demo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdrar2)  that i did.

Comment: Abel, I'm unable to add an <app-header></app-header> to the index.html and get it shown in your demo.

Comment: Go to your index.html file and add the following: `<app-description text="Hello!"></app-description>` after `<my-app>` tag. Is it rendering the description component?

Comment: in stackblitz doesn't work but in my local  the element `<app-description>` works but the `<app-header>` not it could be because app-description is a child.

Comment: Great! You are getting closer to my problem. I couldn't solve it yet

Comment: Great! Let me know!

Comment: Sorry Abel, but I can't make it work with your code. If I don't add the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA the components are not rendered.

Comment: I think it is something with the bootstrapping process. Because if I use `<app-description text="some hardcoded"></app-description>` instead of <app-description text="{{ description }}"></app-description> in the Header template, it is shown...

Comment: No don't think so, as you see I don't need  this  code `schemas : [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]` and it is working good

Comment: You mean in stackblitz? I just see 'loading'. I replicated your code locally and it didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173004/discussion-between-abel-valdez-and-bruno).

Comment: I add my code in github to you check whats wrong in your code. [src](https://github.com/AbelValdez/Angular-customelements-child)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

If we see my description.component.ts the HTML tag for this component is *app-description*:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-description',
  ...
```

And in my app.module.ts I'm registering the DescriptionComponent as an angular element like this:

```
const DescriptionElement = createCustomElement(DescriptionComponent, {injector: this.injector});
customElements.define('app-description', DescriptionElement);
```

Note that I'm declaring the element with the same tag as the component.
I changed that to:

```
const DescriptionElement = createCustomElement(DescriptionComponent, {injector: this.injector});
customElements.define('app-descriptions', DescriptionElement);
```

and now I can use the custom element in any HTML file like this:

```
<body>
  <app-descriptions text="Probando 1"></app-descriptions>
</body>
```

and use the DescriptionComponent inside my Header template like:

```
 <app-description text="{{descriptionText}}"></app-description>
```

My conclusion is: **Declare your Angular Element with a different HTML tag from the component's HTML tag.**

Thanks to everyone who collaborated!

Comment: yes it's obvious, angular directives should be unique for distinguishability, i didn't know the problem was that, good to hear you solved your problem btw.